# В качестве параметров два массива целых чисел. Найти произведение каждого массива, после найти разность двух массивов. Как записать в одну строку?

Tags: javascript, массивы

```
//решил без записи в одну строчку
function example(a, b) {
    let multiplayA = 1;
    for (let item of a) {
        multiplayA *= item;
    };

    let multiplayB = 1;
    for (let item of b) {
        multiplayB *= item;
    };

    let result = multiplayA - multiplayB;

    return result;
};
```

Comment: .......А зачем?

Comment: Кинуть в минификатор.... И он выдаст в одну строку

Comment: Спасибо, но я только изучаю JS, поэтому пытаюсь сам написать код. Может подскажите, что применить чтобы сделать это задание самому?

Comment: Ничего. Максимум reduce применить со стрелочной функцией. Сделать это в одну строку, которую поймёт без напрягов любой разраб, а не только бездушная машина - нельзя никак.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю зачем, но можно так:

```js
const productAndSub = (arr1, arr2) => 
  arr1.reduce((a, b) => {return a * b}, 1) - 
  arr2.reduce((a, b) => {return a * b}, 1);
  
console.log(productAndSub([1, 2, 3], [-1, -2, -3]));
```

UPD: Исключительно для Алексея Шиманского :) реально в одну строку:

```
const productAndSub = (arr1, arr2) => arr1.reduce((a, b) => {return a * b}, 1) - arr2.reduce((a, b) => {return a * b}, 1);
```

UPD 2: Исключительно для Алексея Шиманского :) `minify + uglify` ([воспользовался этим сервисом](https://tools.webdevpuneet.com/js-minify-and-uglify/)):

```
const productAndSub=(c,d)=>c.reduce((c,d)=>c*d,1)-d.reduce((c,d)=>c*d,1);
```

Comment: Это не одна строка 

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Только ради тебя обновил свой ответ! :)

Comment: Minify  + uglify ещё и будет отл 

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Готово! 

Comment: .............